# Spring with mySql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

My partners have the same code, but i am the only one that has this problem.
I have the same mySql and Spring version. Here's the exception I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
  Error creating bean with name 'dataBaseUsage': Invocation of init method failed; 
  nested exception is 
  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
  could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
  org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
could not execute statement

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Unknown column 'roles' in 'field list'
```

DataBaseUsage is @Controller

Thank you

Comment: do you maybe miss some migration / schema adjustment? seems like one of your table misses a field `roles`. This has nothing got to do with the version of the framework and the database but rather with what's stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't have column `roles` in the database table. You should update your database. You can use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.

Comment: that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mapping error to me, check the names of the entity, the pojo fields, the database fields names (if its set to create it). Make sure they all match, maybe something about capital letters.
Im afraid I cant provide further help with that little info.

Comment: i think that it isnt error code  because my partners this code run properly